Windows 10 desktop with Intellij - not detecting physical Android phone when I connect via USB cable
I'm building an Android app in Flutter on my Windows 10 desktop PC.
Just recently, when I attached my Samsung S22+ to the desktop via a USB cable, I noticed that the IntelliJ IDE was not detecting the presence of this mobile phone, as there was no entry in the list of platforms.
Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this?
FYI...  the Windows O/S is detecting the device, as it automatically opens up a File Manager Explorer view of the Android device file system.

From Android Studio doesn't detect my connected physical devices
Go to Settings -> About phone -> Tap on Build number several times, then go to Settings -> Developer -> USB debugging

The Developer USB debugger is already enabled. The problem is that the phone was recognised and working until a couple of weeks ago.  Now its not.
